# How can I make a Eloquent request where I want 2 models that have similar relationships?

Tags: laravel, eloquent

The title may be confusing, so read the body please.

Basically, I am building an "algorithm" that will match candidates with the proper job offers. On their profile, the candidate can put that they are available like on the morning and the nights. When the employer create a job offer, they can say: "this job is night and afternoon".

We can see that they have matching relationships: candidate has morning and **nights** and the job offer has **night** and afternoon. If it happens, I want the Laravel to return this result (or consider it since I am chaining where methods).

### tables:
candidate

id

### availability_candidate

id,
availability_id,
candidate_id

### job_offer

id

### availability_job_offer

id,
job_offer_id,
availability_id

I am pretty sure there is a way to do that, return the result if at least one relationship is matching, but I have no idea how...

I can't make a polymorphic relationship, my data is already in my database, etc.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You're going to want the 'many to many' eloquent relationship.

https://laravel.com/docs/8.x/eloquent-relationships#many-to-many

Also checkout:

https://laravel.com/docs/8.x/eloquent-relationships#defining-relationships

In the Candidate model

```
namespace App\Models;

use Illuminate\Database\Eloquent\Model;

class Candidate extends Model
{
    /**
     * The Availability that belong to the Candidate.
     */
    public function availability()
    {
        return $this->belongsToMany('App\Models\Availability', 'availability_candidate', 'candidate_id', 'availability_id');
    }
}
```

Then in the availability model

```
namespace App\Models;

use Illuminate\Database\Eloquent\Model;

class Availability extends Model
{
    /**
     * The Candidate that belong to the Availability.
     */
    public function candidate()
    {
        return $this->belongsToMany('App\Models\Candidate', 'availability_candidate', 'availability_id', 'candidate_id');
    }
}

    /**
     * The Job Offer that belong to the Availability.
     */
    public function jobs()
    {
        return $this->belongsToMany('App\Models\Jobs', 'availability_job_offer', 'availability_id', 'job_id');
    }
}
```

Then in the Job model

```
class Availability extends Model
{
    /**
     * The Availability that belong to the Job.
     */
    public function availability()
    {
        return $this->belongsToMany('App\Models\Availability', 'availability_job_offer', 'job_id', 'availability_id');
    }
}
```

Finally to retrieve the jobs you would:

```
$jobs = $candidate->availability->jobs->where('key_on_jobs_table', $value)->get();
```

Comment: Great! But how do I get this in a request? Like, if I have multiple things like availibity (field of work, job type, etc). How would that be restricted in something similar to a builder query? (where, whereHas, etc).

Comment: I have edited the answer to reflect your comment. More info can be found here: https://laravel.com/docs/8.x/eloquent-relationships#defining-relationships